# iPhone to PC data transfer

Tags: iphone

I need to transfer data from iPhone to PC using USB from My App. How can i do this.

Thanks,

Comment: I would go via a website rather than direct to a PC - or use wifi and bonjour - otherwise you will make things overly complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume you use the Accessory framework that is part of 3.0.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAAccessory_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: `ExternalAcessory` won't talk to your computer.

Answer (score 1):

If iTunes and iCloud is not your cup of tea then use some third party tool like iPhone to Computer Transfer to [transfer iPhone data to computer](http://transferiphonefiles.iphone-to-pc.com/).

[CopyTrans](http://www.copytrans.net/) is good too.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`ExternalAccessoryFramework` only talks to MFi verified accessories via 30-pin connector.

You may make use of File-Sharing Support since iOS 3.2. Add the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key to your application’s Info.plist file and set the value of the key to `YES`. Write your data as files in `/Documents` and retrieve them from iTunes. This satisfies your requirement of USB data transfer.